# Comparison of the American and European call deltas

Tags: options, american-options, delta

Suppose the interest rate is zero. A stock with price $S(t)$ at time $t$ pays only one dividend at time $t_1$ such that $S(s_+)=S(t_1^-)q$ where $q\in[0,1]$ is a constant. Consider a European call and an American call with the same strike $K$ and expiry $T>t_1>0$ at time $0$. Define
$$C_{\text{E}}(S_t,t):=\mathbf E\big[(S(T)-K)_+\big|S(t)=S_t\big]$$
Then
$$C_{\text{E}}(S_0,0)=\mathbf E\big[(S(T)-K)_+\big|S(0)=S_0\big]=\mathbf E\big[C_{\text{E}}(S_{t_1^-},t)\big|S(0)=S_0\big].$$
The only time this American option may exercise early is time $s$. So
$$C_{\text{A}}(S_0,0)=\mathbf E\big[\max\left(S(t_1^-)-K,\,C_{\text E}(S_{t_1^-},t_1^-)\right)\big|S(0)=S_0\big].$$

Is the following comparison of the American and the European call deltas true?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_{\text{A}}(S,0)\ge\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_{\text{E}}(S,0).$$

Comment: Never really thought about this (good question), but how about this: if you 'Europeanize' an American option I suspect its IVs will be higher than that of the European. Hence, the difference between the deltas will depend on the value of vanna. I can see many holes with this shortcut, so not saying at all that it is right. Just a thought.

Comment: @Frido: Well, "Europeanization", and thus the corresponding IV, is not a well defined concept. It is a somewhat heuristic. I actually have a proof. I just need some time to write it up.

Comment: Yes it is heuristic. Once you have written up your proof, it would be great to post it here as an answer.

Comment: @Frido: That is my plan. :-) The proof can be generalized to the case with continuous time dividend.

Comment: @Frido: Have you seen my proof below? It is not the most tidily formatted yet. I will revamp it later.

Comment: I did yes, yesterday already (+1). It looks good to me. I am wondering if you could prove it also using the local time formula (Ito-Tanaka-Meyer) for $C_E$ at time $t_1$.

Comment: @Frido: The local time Ito-Tanaka-Meyer formula may be used to provide and alternative derivation of the relation $C_\text E(S,t_1^-)=C_\text E(qS,t_1^+)$. Is that what you have in mind? I do not see how it could be further employed to derive the final bounds in place of, say, the Feynman-Kac formula.

Answer (score 3):

This is true, $\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text A(S,0)\in [0,1]$ and that the difference is bound above.

***Proof:***
Suppose $S\ge 0$ follows a local volatility process
$$dS(t) = \sigma(S(t),t)S(t)\,dB(t)$$
where $B(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion. We can extend this dynamics later to account for a stochastic volatility process.

Because $C_\text E(S,t_1^-)=C_\text E(qS,t_1^+)$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S,t_1^-)=q\frac{\partial}{\partial x}C_\text E(x=qS,t_1^+)<q<1,\,\forall t<T$,
$S-K=C_{\text E}(S,t_1^-)$ has a unique solution for $S$. We denote it by $S_c$. Because the value of a call, either American or European, such as $C_\text E(S,t)$, is convext with respect to stock $S$, $\min_{S\ge S_c}\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S,t_1^-)=\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S=S_c,t_1^-)$.

Let $\Theta$ be [the Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). At time $t<s$, both calls, and their difference $C=C_{\text A}-C_{\text E}$ due to the linearity thereof, satisfy
$$\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\frac12(\sigma S)^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}\bigg]C(S,t)=0,$$
$$C(S,t=t_1^-)=\big(S-K-C_\text E(S,t_1)\big)\Theta(S-S_c).$$
Take partial derivative of the above partial differential equation over $S$ and $C_1:=\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C$. We have
$$\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+uS\frac{\partial}{\partial S} +\frac12(\sigma S)^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}\bigg]C_1(S,t)=0, \tag1\label{1}$$
$$C_1(S,t=t_1^-)=\Big(1-\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S,t_1)\Big)\Theta(S-S_c),$$
where $u:=\frac1{2S}\frac{\partial}{\partial S}(\sigma S)^2$.
It can be shown by repeating the same methodology here that
$$0\le C_1(S,t_1^-)\le1-\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S=S_c,t_1^-).$$
By [the strong maximum principle of elliptical and parabolic partial differential equation](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Econst/maxhar.pdf) (c.f. also [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle#cite_ref-1)),
$$0=\inf_S C_1(S,t_1^-)\le C_1(S,t)\le\sup_S(S,t_1^-)=1-\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S=S_c,t_1^-), \quad\forall t<t_1. \tag2\label2$$

An alternative to the last step is [the Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula).

The solution to Equation $\eqref1$ is
$$C_1(S,t)=\mathbf E\big[C_1(S(t_1^-),t_1^-)\big|S(t_1^-)=S\big]$$
under the probability measure such that $S(t)$ is a new Ito process
$$dS=uSdt+\sigma S\,dB.$$
Equation $\eqref2$ is then obvious.

To recapitulate, we have proved -- more than what is sought by the question -- that
$$0\le\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\big(C_{\text{A}}(S,t)-C_{\text{E}}(S,t)\big)\le1-\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S=S_c,t_1^-), \quad\forall t<t_1,$$
which is the desired result for the difference.

Apply the same method, we can show
\begin{align*}
& C_\text A(S,T) = C_\text E(S,T) = (S-K)_+ \\
\implies & \frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text A(S,T) = \frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S,T) = \Theta(S-K)\in [0,1] \\
\implies & \frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text A(S,t_1^+) = \frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text E(S,t_1^+) \in [0,1] 
\end{align*}
and thus
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial S}C_\text A(S,t)\in [0,1], \quad\forall t<t_1.$$

$$\tag*{$\square$}$$